# Obtener información de archivo .txt en PHP

Tags: php, html

estoy creando un generador de sentencias u oraciones aleatorias para, al final, unir todas las opciones elegidas y formar una oración entera.

Problema: No logro separar la información de un archivo .txt en subarrays para así poder elegir 3 al azar y mostrarlas.

Solo obtengo "11111111111111" donde deberían estar las oraciones.

Código PHP y HTML:

```
<?php


$introducción = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/intro.txt"));

$desarrollo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/desarrollo.txt"));

$personajes = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/personajes.txt"));

$personajes2 = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/personajes2.txt"));

$nudo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/nudo.txt"));

$desenlace = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/desenlace.txt"));

$final = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/final.txt"));

$titulo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/titulo.txt"));



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <center>
    <b size= 50>Crea tu propia historia de fantasía</b>
    <p>La idea es simple, elije una oración o una frase de cada sección para crear así una historia con o sin sentido de lo que más te guste para al final unirlo en una historia</p>
    </center>
</head>
<body> 
    <center>
        <div>
            <p>Primero empecemos con una introducción:</p>
            <ul>            
                <?php foreach ($introducción as $sentencia) { ?>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo shuffle($introducción); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>  
            </ul>

        </div>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado esperado? $introduccion ya es un array.

Comment: El resultado esperado es que lea (en este caso como puse un foreach) y me imprima en un echo cada una de las oraciones (osea, cada item del array) que hay en el texto intro.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que tu array de introducciones imprima sus elementos de manera aleatoria deberias llamar a la funcion suffle antes de entrar al foreach.

```
<?php


$introducción = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/intro.txt"));

$desarrollo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/desarrollo.txt"));

$personajes = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/personajes.txt"));

$personajes2 = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/personajes2.txt"));

$nudo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/nudo.txt"));

$desenlace = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/desenlace.txt"));

$final = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/final.txt"));

$titulo = explode("\n", file_get_contents("Cuentos/titulo.txt"));

shuffle($introducción);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <center>
    <b size= 50>Crea tu propia historia de fantasía</b>
    <p>La idea es simple, elije una oración o una frase de cada sección para crear así una historia con o sin sentido de lo que más te guste para al final unirlo en una historia</p>
    </center>
</head>
<body> 
    <center>
        <div>
            <p>Primero empecemos con una introducción:</p>
            <h1></h1>
            <ul>            

                <?php foreach ($introducción as $sentencia) { ?>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $sentencia; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>  
            </ul>

        </div>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, la había pensado esa, pero me manda el mismo error: 
Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: pero estas haciendo el echo $sentencia ? Porque ese error te daria si le das echo $introduccion dentro del foreach

Comment: Gracias! Estaba haciendo el echo en $introducción, porque creía que esa era la variable que tenia toda la información!